# JSON Schema validator compatibility

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to understand how a single JSON Schema behaves when used in different validators. Some validators define custom keywords. For example ajv validator [ajv-keywords](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-keywords#prohibited) package defines a `prohibited` keyword that is not part of the JSON Schema standard. JSON Schema on the other hand defines the `required` keyword that would seem to be the polar opposite of `prohibited`. JSON Schema also defines a `oneOf` combinator that can be used to validate that the input should match one and only one of several schema definitions.

Consider the following schema example. By reading the json schema specification, I get the impression that the example json schema should validate any json object when used in ajv. However, according to the unknown keyword rules, validators are supposed to ignore any keywords they do not support. So, I imagine that another validator would ignore the custom `prohibited` keyword, causing the schema to reject an input with property `foo`. Is this correct or am I failing to read the json schema specification?

```
{
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["foo"]
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "prohibited": ["foo"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. A standard JSON Schema validator will fail validation for an object that has a property "foo". You should be very careful using non-standard keywords if you expect your schemas to be used by standard validators.

It should be okay to use custom keywords as long as you follow the principle of **progressive enhancement**. Effectively, that means the behavior should degrade as gracefully as possible if the custom keyword is ignored. Your example violates this principle because you end up with a false negative result if `prohibited` is ignored.

An simple example that does follow progressive enhancement might look like this...

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {}
  },
  "required": ["foo"],
  "prohibited": ["bar"]
}
```

If I run this through a standard validator, all assertions work as expected except `prohibited` which is ignored. Assuming a client-server architecture, this allows clients to *mostly* validate their requests before sending them to the server. The server then does it's own validation with a validator that understands the custom keywords and can respond with an error if "bar" is present.